# Sub-covering of a local coefficient system

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I've some trouble understanding this explanation of the proof of lemma 4.7 in Davis and Kirk "Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology".

> **Lemma 4.7** Any local coefficient system $A\hookrightarrow E \to B$ is of the form  $$ A \hookrightarrow \tilde{B}\times_{\pi_1B} A \to B $$

They build the holodromy map $\pi_1 B \to \text{Aut}(A)$ and then claim that using a standard covering space argument one is done.

I noticed that this problem was addressed in [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404647/local-coefficient-system-and-universal-cover) but there is a passage in the answer which are unclear to me:

> it's claimed that, after picking $x \in B$, for every choice of $a \in p^{-1}(x)$ there is an associated sub-cover of $E$. **How?** I mean, the condition given is a fibre-wise condition, so I need to make a choice for every fibre, why all these choices glue together in a  sub-cover?

My guess is to somewhat express this as a quotient of $E$ by some subgroup of the deck-transformation group, but it's unclear to me how to proceed.

NB: Since the answer is very old, I decided to ask for help in a separate question.